# How to add the text before the line in whole file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have list of domain in text file and I need to add *127.0.0.1* ip before the line in whole file. Example as below:

domain.txt

```
....
abc.com
...
```

I want to generate HOSTS file like

```
...
127.0.0.1 abc.com
...
```

In text file, I have thousand of domain entry.

Comment: Is it alway 127.0.0.1 you want to put there?

Comment: @Videonauth yes

Comment: You want to put `127.0.0.1` only before the domain `abc.com` or on all the domains i.e. on all lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve that with `sed` in the following way:

```
sed -i 's/^/127.0.0.1 /' /path/filename.txt
```

Best make a backup of the file before, I'm right now not sure if you need to escape the space or not. To make a backup directly when you run sed you can use the following line:

```
sed -i_bak -e 's/^/127.0.0.1 /' /path/filename.txt
```

A bit more information about `sed` you can [find here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/chap_05.html).

Comment: Same thing, how to put after the line?

Comment: Use `$` instead of `^`, to add to the end of line.

Answer (score 8):

If you want the original to be intact:

```
sed 's/^/127.0.0.1 /' domain.txt > new_domain.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

#### GUI answer using GEdit

1. Open up your file in Gedit. Let's say I want to add '127.0.0.1 ' to the beginning of all lines in this text file.

[image]

2. Using search and replace feature, search for `\n` and replace it with `\n127.0.0.1`  then click `Replace all` button as shown below:

[image]

3. This is your result:
   **Disclaimer:** You will have to manually enter the replace with text `127.0.0.1`  at the beginning of the first line.

[image]

Comment: Also good option...

Answer (score 3):

[awk](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/AWK) is a good option to this issue. Explaining in two examples:

```
# Let's consider a file domain.txt with lines like this:
# <domain> <user> <user> ....
# Ex: domain.zzz.yy user01 user02

# Extracting the first field of each line
awk '{ print "127.0.0.1 " $1;}' domain.txt

# produces: 127.0.0.1 domain.zzz.yy
# filter only first field $1=domain.zzz.yy
# $1: first field, $2: second field, and so on

# Extracting the whole line
awk '{ print "127.0.0.1 " $0;}' domain.txt

# produce: 127.0.0.1 domain.zzz.yy user01 user02
# $0: whole line
```

Comment: Well, this depends on the assumption that each line contains only one "word" (i.e., it contains no spaces), which may be true if each line is a domain name (with no comments).  Otherwise, your answer retains only the first "word" on each line and discards the remainder.  `awk '{ print "127.0.0.1 " $0}'` is a more general answer.

Comment: Important note @G-Man, I'm going to update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to add before :

```
$ printf "127.0.0.1 %s\n" $(cat domain.txt)
```

> %s means string of line on file
>
> \n means prints the content in new line